# Loading model relationships with Backbone.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, model, backbone.js, relationship

I am writing my first Backbone.js app with a Rails REST backend, and one thing that is puzzling me is the relationship between models.

This app that I am writing will have `Ticket` and `Client` as models. I have setup both `Tickets` and `Clients` collections as well.

It turns out I have a few thousand customers and I wouldn't like to load them in memory, instead I'd like to lazily load the customer when a ticket refers to it.

I have tried a very naive approach that obviously doesn't work because `Model#fetch()` method is asynchronous.

Here's my Ticket model so far (in *CoffeeScript*):

```
class Deputy.Models.Ticket extends Backbone.Model

    initialize: ->
        @fetchClient()

    fetchClient: ->
        @client = new Deputy.Models.Client()
        @client.set id: @get('userid')
        @client.fetch()

    clientName: ->
        first = @client.get('firstname')
        last = @client.get('lastname')
        "#{first} #{last}"
```

As you can imagine, the `clientName()` function always returns "undefined undefined", because fetch didn't return when the call is made.

What is the right way of handling this kinds of data relationship? Please note that I don't mind if you take a step back and say I am using the wrong approach and suggest me something instead.

Any pointers, articles, or anything else would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`client.fetch()` accepts a `success` option that will be fired upon completion. When you fire `fetchClient` you should add loading UI (could be something as simple as replacing a button with a spinning icon) and when the client finishes loading continue displaying the name.

In JavaScript you would do something like this:

```
fetchClient: function() {
  var client = new Deputy.Models.Client();
  client.set({ id: this.get('userid') });
  client.fetch({ success: this.fetchClientSuccess });
  // Or maybe the following depending on how you set up your code.
  // client.fetch({ success: Deputy.Models.fetchClientSuccess });
},

fetchClientSuccess: function(lead, response) {
  Deputy.Models.clientName(lead);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However what does `Deputy.Models.clientName(lead)` does exactly and where does it come from?